# Using fused location provider via LocationManager

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I'd like to use the fused location provider via the Android LocationManager API because:

- I'd prefer not to make the app, [Phonelocator](https://github.com/ten20/phonelocator-android/), dependent on google play services
- The existing implementation is already working and tested

It appears that the this is possible. Just pass the the string "fused" as a location provider on a phone with google play services installed.

I'd like the option to use the [PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY) profile. I suspect that, by default, it's not being used.

Has anybody worked out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [android-play-location](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location) samples, as they demonstrate how to use FusedLocationApi.  Something like:

```
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```